# Difficulty in removing zero values in decimal numbers?

Tags: c#, sorting, decimal

I wrote a code that will sort based on decimals. The quick sort algorithm. 
But my issue is the removal of the number 0 in some decimals. Eg 723.1000 becomes 723.1 Numbers are important to me because I want to be displayed and stored as

Now how can I do this without removing the zeros in decimal numbers

We may see these numbers in an array

**Zeros will not be removed.**

10.20 ==> 10.2

or

50.60000 ==> 50.6

or

145698.154780 ===> 145698.15478

So many zeros are not fixed

And this is my problem.

```
internal class Sorter
{
    public string[] QuickSort(string[] array, int low, int high)
    {
        if (low < high)
        {
            int p = Partition(array, low, high);
            QuickSort(array, low, p - 1);
            QuickSort(array, p + 1, high);
        }

        return array;
    }

    private static int Partition(string[] array, int low, int high)
    {
        int left = low + 1, right = high;
        string temp;
        double pivot = double.Parse(array[low]);
        int piv;

        while (left <= right)
        {
            while (left <= right && Convert.ToDouble(array[left]) <= pivot)


                left++;

            while (left <= right && Convert.ToDouble(array[right]) >= pivot)


                right--;

            if (left < right)
            {
                temp = array[left];
                array[left] = array[right];
                array[right] = temp;
            }
        }
        if (right == high)
            piv = high;
        else if (right == low)
            piv = low;
        else
            piv = left - 1;
        array[low] = array[piv];
        array[piv] = pivot.ToString();
        return piv;
    }
}
```

Comment: Couple issues: 1) trailing zeros do not affect the value itself, so it's not 100% what you are asking about; 2) you speak about decimals but use `double`, that's fundamentally different; 3) why do you keep parsing and coverting the values again and again? You should better convert `string[]` into `double[]` before sorting, and back to `string[]` after sorting.

Comment: Check the updated anwer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with [Double.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
   double d=723.1000;
   string s = d.ToString("0.0");
```

Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) for more formatting options.

**Update**
You can try this :

```
string s = d.ToString().TrimEnd('0');
```

**Update 2**:
As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574656/string-to-double-skips-last-decimal-if-it-is-zero) :

> double doesn't keep insignificant digits - there's no difference between 1.5 and 1.50000 as far as double is concerned.
>
> If you want to preserve insignificant digits, use decimal instead. It
>   may well be more appropriate for you anyway, depending on your exact
>   context. (We have very little context to go on here...)

So you can use this `decimal` instead of `double`:

```
decimal d = 723.1000M;
string s = d.ToString();
```

Comment: We may see these numbers in an array
Zeros will not be removed.
10.20 ==> 10.2

or

50.60000 ==> 50.6

or

145698.154780 ===> 145698.15478

So many zeros are not fixed

And this is my problem.

Comment: Answer is no different code

The answer is both code
723.1

I want to display the number 723.1000.

Answer (score 1):

try like this [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx),

```
decimal d = 0.00000000000010000000000m;
string custom = d.ToString("0.#########################");
// gives: 0,0000000000001
string general = d.ToString("G29");
// gives: 1E-13
```

Comment: Zeros will not be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You may try some linq to sort something like

```
double[] myDubleNumber = { 15.00003,  1758.4856, 20.123, 1478.0214,120.0223 };

            var result = myDubleNumber.OrderBy(x => x).Select(x => Math.Round(x, 2));

            foreach (var d in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(d);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to be `public double[] QuickSort(double[] array, int low, int high)`

There should be 2 parts in your program:

1. Input a numeric array and output the sorted one;
2. Format and show the result.

In the first step, please don't consider about the removal of the number 0.

In the second step, please use `.toString()` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to format a number.