# Double to String Conversion without losing exponential part

Tags: c#

I'm trying to add two double numbers say, 1234567890123456.00 and 1.00 and the summation will be stored into a string.

Results are as follows:

> 1234567890123456.00 + 1.00 = 1234567890123457.00

Obvious that it will print as 1.23456789012346E+15 in double form.

But if I'm trying to convert it to string by using method ToString("F") or ToString("#") it results 1234567890123460.00. Where I'm losing 7(the last digit)?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     double d = 1234567890123456;
     double d2 = 1;
     double d3 = d + d2;

     Console.WriteLine(d3);
     Console.WriteLine(d3.ToString("F"));
}
```

Please help me to correct the code or to find an alternative.

Comment: But string output is must be in 1234567890123457.00 or 1234567890123457 format.

Comment: You can use `decimal` instead.

Comment: Go for `decimal` as discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574656/string-to-double-skips-last-decimal-if-it-is-zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     double d = 1234567890123456;
     double d2 = 1;
     double d3 = d + d2;

     Console.WriteLine(d3);
     Console.WriteLine(d3.ToString("R"));
}
```

R - round-trip solved my problem and I'm getting expected result as 1234567890123457

[Binary floating point and .NET](http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/floatingpoint.html)

Answer (score 1):

Double type has [15-16 decimal precision digits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx) and your d value has 16 significant decimal digits, so you are stressing that limit:

```
double d = 1234567890123456;
```

That limit (of the significant digits) comes from the [mantissa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) which in the [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) [binary64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) standard is actually 15.95 significant decimal digits.

[Decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) could be a good alternative.