# How to get max value of List<> in double datatype

Tags: c#, list, double, max

I am trying to get `Max` value from `List<>`, but it's returning rounded value to `integer`. Is there some special way how to proceed this?

```
private List<double> dataX = new List<double>();

double maxVal = dataX.Max<double>();
Debug.WriteLine("max: " + maxVal);
```

Edit:
As requested here is feeding data:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                data.Add(new ChartData(i, rand.NextDouble() * 10));
                Debug.WriteLine(data.Last<ChartData>().Y);
            }
```

My debug window shows this:

```
5,9358753151893
7,87125875608588
3,77212246589927
9,36056426230844
2,27154730924943
9,80201833872218
5,7350595275569
3,04650606729393
5,81677517658881
0,0514464220271662
max: 8
```

So I don't think the feeding side is wrong. And for whole picture, here you can see ChartData type:

```
public class ChartData
    {
        public double X { get; set; }
        public double Y { get; set; }

        public ChartData(double X, double Y)
        {
            this.X = X;
            this.Y = Y;
        }
    }
```

And how I'm getting simple `List` from my ChartData `class`:

```
private List<ChartData> data = new List<ChartData>();
private List<double> dataX = new List<double>();

void updateMaxMin()
        {
            dataX.Clear();
            dataY.Clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                dataX.Add(data[i].X);
                dataY.Add(data[i].Y);
            }
        }
```

Comment: you are probably rounding while feeding the list. Max works just fine.

Comment: It works fine https://dotnetfiddle.net/BQ8vBJ

Comment: Show where you fill the list, you are looking at the wrong place

Comment: The code should work as intended. You should check the output on your side again. Maybe checking the debug settings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found mistake. I have been calculating max value from different array. So i got correct max value anyway. There should be:

```
double maxVal = dataY.Max<double>();
```

instead of

```
double maxVal = dataX.Max<double>();
```

So I guess, this isn't much helping, so I will delete this question after you realized I did basic fault.

Thank you all anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There are two *likely* scenarios here.

1. You are rounding the values as you enter them into the list (as @sam mentioned in his comment).
2. You are expecting a double value ending in 0 to show these decimal places. A double will always drop off the insignificant digits. So for example, 1.500 will be truncated to 1.5. This is how doubles were intended to work. Another article that briefly talks about this is [Double Skips last decimal if zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574656/string-to-double-skips-last-decimal-if-it-is-zero). If you are looking for a different **Visual** output, I would recommend converting the result to a string and then using string formatting. An example would be the following (using 2 decimal places):

   Console.WriteLine(string.Format("max: {0:0.00}", maxVal));

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the problem is in the way you insert into the list as some had suggested in here (you mentioned about rounded to an integer, so I'm assuming it is probably not visual display related).

Try debug your data in the list:

```
private List<double> dataX = new List<double>();

...

foreach(var data in dataX)
{
     Debug.WriteLine("data: " + data);
}

double maxVal = dataX.Max<double>();
Debug.WriteLine("max: " + maxVal);
```

A possible issue with the way you populate the list could be something like:

```
var myNum = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
foreach (var num in myNum)
{
    dataX.Add(num / 2);
}
```

The data that was added into the dataX is actually an integer (as the division by 2 returns an integer).

Answer (score 0):

double doesn't keep insignificant digits. - there's no difference between 9 and  9.0 and 9.0000

If you want just display purpose use refer this link [C# Double - ToString() formatting with two decimal places but no rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453951/c-sharp-double-tostring-formatting-with-two-decimal-places-but-no-rounding) for convert the double to string with decimal places. but,if you using calculation  it's no need for keeping with decimal places.